# Does a function with instructions before the entry-point label cause problems for anything (linking)?

Tags: assembly, linker, object-files

This is really a linker / object-file question, but tagging with assembly since compilers never do this.  (Although maybe they could!)

Consider this function, where I want to handle one special case with a block of code that's in the same I-cache line as the function entry-point.    To avoid jumping over it in the usual fast-path, **is it safe (wrt. linking / shared libraries / other tools I haven't thought of) to put the code for it ahead of the function's global symbol?**

I know this is silly / overkill, see below.  Mostly I was just curious.  Regardless of whether this technique is useful for making code that actually runs faster in practice, I think it's an interesting question.

```
.globl __nextafter_pjc      // double __nextafter_pjc(double x, double y)
.p2align 6  // unrealistic 64B alignment, just for the sake of argument

// GNU as local labels have the form  .L...
.Lequal_or_unordered:
    jp  .Lunordered
    movaps  %xmm1, %xmm0    # ISO C11 requires returning y, not x.  (matters for  -0.0 == +0.0)
    ret

######### Function entry point / global symbol here #############    
// .p2align something // tuning for Sandybridge, maybe best to just leave this unaligned, since it's only 6B from the alignment boundary
nextafter_pjc:
    ucomisd %xmm1, %xmm0
    je  .Lequal_or_unordered

    xorps   %xmm3, %xmm3
    comisd  %xmm3, %xmm0    // x==+/0.0 can be a special case: the sign bit may change
    je  .Lx_zero

    movq    %xmm0, %rax
    ...  // some mostly-branchless bit-ninjutsu that I have no idea how I'd get gcc to emit from C

    ret

.Lx_zero:
  ...
  ret
.Lunordered:
  ...
  ret
```

(BTW, I'm messing around with asm for [`nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter) because I was curious about how glibc implemented it.  It turns out the [current implementation](https://www.sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=math/s_nextafter.c) compiles to some really nasty code with a ton of branches.  e.g. checking both inputs for NaN should be done with an FP compare, because that's super-fast esp. in the non-NaN case.)

---

In disassembly output, instructions before the label are grouped after the previous function's instructions.  e.g.

```
0000000000400ad0 <frame_dummy>:
                ...
  400af0:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  400af1:       e9 7a ff ff ff          jmpq   400a70 <register_tm_clones>
  400af6:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400afd:       00 00 00 
  400b00:       7a 56                   jp     400b58 <__nextafter_pjc+0x52>
  400b02:       0f 28 c1                movaps %xmm1,%xmm0
  400b05:       c3                      retq   

0000000000400b06 <__nextafter_pjc>:
  400b06:       66 0f 2e c1             ucomisd %xmm1,%xmm0
  400b0a:       74 f4                   je     400b00 <frame_dummy+0x30>
  400b0c:       0f 57 db                xorps  %xmm3,%xmm3
  400b0f:       66 0f 2f c3             comisd %xmm3,%xmm0
  400b13:       74 4b                   je     400b60 <__nextafter_pjc+0x5a>
  400b15:       66 48 0f 7e c0          movq   %xmm0,%rax
                ...
```

Note that the 4th instruction in the main body, `comisd`, starts at `400b0f` (and isn't fully contained in the first 16B-aligned block that contains the function entry-point).  So it's maybe not really optimal for instruction-fetch and decode for the no-taken-branches fast-path to do it exactly this way.  This is just an example, though.

So this *appears* to work, even at the beginning of a file.  It does confuse `objdump`, and isn't ideal in `gdb` (but it's not a big problem).  ELF object files don't record symbol sizes anyway, so `nm --print-size` doesn't do anything anyway.  (And `nm --size-sort --print-size`, which tries to calculate symbol sizes, strangely didn't include my function.)

I don't know much about Windows object files.  Does anything worse happen there?

I'm slightly worried about correctness here: **does anything ever try to copy single functions out of object files by taking bytes from their symbol address to the following symbol address**?  Normal library archives (`ar` for static libraries) and linkers copy whole object files around, right?  Otherwise they couldn't be sure they were copying all necessary static data.

---

This function is probably called infrequently, and we want to minimize the cache pollution (I$, uop-cache, branch-predictors).  And if anything, optimize for the un-cached case with cold branch predictors.

This is probably silly because the un-cached case can only happen infrequently.  However, if *many* functions are all optimized this way, the total cache footprint will decrease and maybe they *will* all fit in cache.

Note that recent Intel CPUs don't do static branch prediction at all, so there's no reason to favor forward branches for usually-not-taken branches.

Instead of defaulting to taken for backward branches / not-taken for forward for "unknown" branches that aren't in the BHT, my understanding of [Agner Fog's microarch doc (the branch prediction chapter)](http://agner.org/optimize/) is that they don't check whether a branch is "new" or not.  They just use whatever entry is already in the BHT, without clearing it.  [This may not be exactly true, though, for Nehalem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mechanical-sympathy/pMN6TbXwOUc/dPiM38i9DwAJ).

Comment: Function size is important for shared libraries though and there is a `.size` directive in `gas` which `gcc` indeed uses and `nm` shows. I forgot what this is actually used for. Or maybe for functions only the symbol `.type` is important and size matters for non-functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple way to make this look totally normal: put a non-global label in front of the code.  This makes it look like (or actually *be*) a `static` helper function.

Non-global functions can call each other with any calling convention they want.  C compilers can even make code like this with link-time / whole-program optimization, or even just optimization of `static` functions within a compilation unit.  Jumps (rather than calls) to another function are already used for tail-call optimization.

The "helper function" code can jump into the main function at somewhere other than the entry point.  I'm sure that's not a problem for linkers though.  That would only break if a linker changed the distance between the helper and the main function (by inserting something between them) without adjusting relative jumps that cross the gap that it widened.  I don't think any linker *would* insert anything that way in the first place, and doing so without fixing any branches is clearly a bug.

I'm not sure if there are any pitfalls in generating `.size` ELF metadata.  I think I've read that it's important for functions that will be linked into shared libraries.

The following should work fine with any tool that deals with object files:

```
.globl __nextafter_pjc      // double __nextafter_pjc(double x, double y)
.p2align 6  // unrealistic 64B alignment, just for the sake of argument


nextafter_helper:  # not a local label, but not .globl either
.Lequal_or_unordered:
    jp  .Lunordered
    movaps  %xmm1, %xmm0    # ISO C11 requires returning y, not x.  (matters for  -0.0 == +0.0)
    ret

######### Function entry point / global symbol here #############    
// .p2align something?
__nextafter_pjc:
    ucomisd %xmm1, %xmm0
    je  .Lequal_or_unordered

    ...    
    ret
```

We don't *need* a plain label and a "local" label, but using different labels for different purposes means less modification is needed when re-arranging things.  (e.g. you can put the `.Lequal_or_unordered` block somewhere else without renaming it back to a `.L` and changing all the jumps that target it.)  `nextafter_equal_or_unordered` would work as a single name.