# Measuring size of a function generated with Clang/LLVM?

Tags: c, embedded, clang, llvm, low-level

Recently, when working on a project, I had a need to measure the size of a C function in order to be able to copy it somewhere else, but was not able to find any "clean" solutions (ultimately, I just wanted to have a label inserted at the end of the function that I could reference).

Having written the LLVM backend for this architecture (while it may look like ARM, it isn't) and knowing that it emitted assembly code for that architecture, I opted for the following hack (I think the comment explains it quite well):

```
/***************************************************************************
 * if ENABLE_SDRAM_CALLGATE is enabled, this function should NEVER be called
 * from C code as it will corrupt the stack pointer, since it returns before
 * its epilog. this is done because clang does not provide a way to get the
 * size of the function so we insert a label with inline asm to measure the
 * function. in addition to that, it should not call any non-forceinlined
 * functions to avoid generating a PC relative branch (which would fail if
 * the function has been copied)
 **************************************************************************/
void sdram_init_late(sdram_param_t* P) {
    /* ... */
#ifdef ENABLE_SDRAM_CALLGATE
    asm(
        "b lr\n"
        ".globl sdram_init_late_END\n"
        "sdram_init_late_END:"
    );
#endif
}
```

It worked as desired but required some assembler glue code in order to call it and is a pretty dirty hack that only worked because I could assume several things about the code generation process.

I've also considered other ways of doing this which would work better if LLVM was emitting machine code (since this approach would break once I added an MC emitter to my LLVM backend). The approach I considered involved taking the function and searching for the terminator instruction (which would either be a `b lr` instruction or a variation of `pop ..., lr`) but that could also introduce additional complications (though it seemed better than my original solution).

**Can anyone suggest a cleaner way of getting the size of a C function without having to resort to incredibly ugly and unreliable hacks such as the ones outlined above?**

Comment: Taking the `sizeof` a function is undefined behaviour in C. But you could use the linker when compiling to functions-sections to generate appropriate symbols.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to write `sdram_init_late()` in assembly language?  If so, you will have complete control over how to provide the begin and end of the block of code to copy.

Comment: It could certainly be written in assembly but writing it in C and keeping it together in the same file as other SDRAM initialization code (aside from the routine used to jump to that function and save/restore registers) makes it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right that there aren't any truly portable ways to do this.  Compilers are allowed to re-order functions, so taking the address of the next function in source order isn't safe (but does work in some cases).

---

If you can parse the object file ([maybe with `libbfd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library)), you might be able to get function sizes from that.

clang's [asm output](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-xc+-O3++-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-verbose-asm',source:'int+foo(int+a)+%7B+return+a+*+a+*+2%3B+%7D')),filterAsm:(intel:!t),version:3) has this metadata (the `.size` assembler directive after every function), but I'm not sure whether it ends up in the object file.

```
int foo(int a) { return a * a * 2; }

   ## clang-3.8 -O3 for amd64:
   ## some debug-info lines manually removed
    .globl  foo
foo:
.Lfunc_begin0:
        .cfi_startproc
        imul    edi, edi
        lea     eax, [rdi + rdi]
        ret
.Lfunc_end0:
        .size   foo, .Lfunc_end0-foo   ####### This line
```

---

Compiling this to a `.o` with `clang-3.8 -O3 -Wall -Wextra func-size.c -c`, I can then do:

```
$ readelf --symbols func-size.o 

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 4 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS func-size.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 0000000000000000     7 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 foo   ### This line
```

The three instructions total 7 bytes, which matches up with the `size` output here.  It doesn't include the padding to align the entry point, or the next function: the `.align` directives are outside the two labels that are subtracted to calculate the `.size`.

This probably doesn't work well for stripped executables.  Even their global functions won't still be present in the symbol table of the executable.  So you might need a two-step build process:

- compile your "normal" code
- get sizes of functions you care about into a table, using `readelf | some text processing > sizes.c`
- compile sizes.c
- link everything together

---

#### Caveat

A really clever compiler could compile multiple similar functions to share a common implementation.  So one of the functions jumps into the middle of the other function body.  If you're lucky, all the functions are grouped together, with the "size" of each measuring from its entry point all the way to the end of the blocks of code it uses.  (But that overlap would make the total sizes add up to more than the size of the file.)

Current compilers don't do this, but **you can prevent it by putting the function in a separate compilation unit**, and not using whole-program link-time optimization.

A compiler could decide to put a conditionally-executed block of code before the function entry point, so the branch can use a shorter encoding for a small displacement.  [This makes that block look like a static "helper" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468465/does-a-function-with-instructions-before-the-entry-point-label-cause-problems-fo) which probably wouldn't be included in the "size" calculation for function.  Current compilers never do this, either, though.

---

Another idea, which **I'm not confident is safe**:

Put an `asm volatile` with *just* a label definition at the end of your function, and then assume the function size is at most that + 32 bytes or something.  So when you copy the function, you allocate a buffer 32B larger than your "calculated" size.  Hopefully there's only a "ret" insn beyond the label, but actually it probably goes before the function epilogue which pops all the call-preserved registers it used.

I don't think the optimizer can duplicate an `asm volatile` statement, so it would force the compiler to jump to a common epilogue instead of duplicating the epilogue like it might sometimes for early-out conditions.

But I'm not sure there's an upper bound on how much could end up *after* the asm volatile.

Comment: The `readelf -s` approach is the sane one. If you look at the object code (e.g. `objdump -d func-size`, the object code of the function does take all the 21 bytes. (gcc-4.8.4 and clang-3.5, however, both manage to do it in just 7 bytes, and that's what `readelf -s` shows on their object files, too; also note that the size field is in decimal.) I'd say your answer regarding `readelf -s` is the correct one, and you were just lead astray by your `clang-3.8` generating extra binary code for you, which you didn't notice to check. I think. :)

Comment: @NominalAnimal: 21 bytes was from the default `-O0`.  Not padding, just the usual bloated code.  /facepalm.  I was looking at the same code on godbolt so I could post a link to the asm.  I didn't realize I hadn't actually looked at the disassembly of what I tested on my desktop.  Sorry for wasting people's time with that confusion!

Comment: :) For what it's worth, I do rely on sizes reported by `readelf -s`. However, I'm always worried about jumps outside the function; that someday, a compiler will find a way to merge function implementations to save on code use. It would be quite good thing to do (less cache pollution for one), but it would completely break this particular use case. So, I'd personally add a warning about that, and suggest that such functions are compiled in a separate compilation unit, to avoid exactly that scenario.

Comment: @nominalanimal  for what it's worth, there are compilers already that do this.  The ARM realview compiler and the Greenhills compilers (for ARM at least) can do link-time optimizations and fold functions together if the're sufficiently similar.

Comment: @RussSchultz: gcc can [merge identical function (`-fipa-icf`):
"Perform Identical Code Folding for functions and read-only variables. The optimization reduces code size and may disturb unwind stacks by replacing a function by equivalent one with a different name."](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)  But AFAIK it doesn't mix and match, so you don't get a function body that jumps into the middle of another function body.  i.e. it won't factor two similar functions into separate entry points and a common helper function.  Do the compilers you're talking about do that?

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, the GHS one would.   Or at least with it turned on, debugging was even more problematic than it normally is.