# Is there any operation in C analogous to this assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, function-pointers

Today, I played around with incrementing function pointers in assembly code to create alternate entry points to a function:

```
.386
.MODEL FLAT, C
.DATA
    INCLUDELIB MSVCRT
    EXTRN puts:PROC
    HLO DB "Hello!", 0
    WLD DB "World!", 0
.CODE
    dentry PROC
        push offset HLO
        call puts           
        add esp, 4
        push offset WLD
        call puts
        add esp, 4
        ret
    dentry ENDP
    main PROC
        lea edx, offset dentry
        call edx
        lea edx, offset dentry
        add edx, 13
        call edx
        ret
    main ENDP
END
```

(I know, technically this code is invalid since it calls `puts` without the CRT being initialized, but it works without any assembly or runtime errors, at least on MSVC 2010 SP1.)

Note that in the second call to `dentry` I took the address of the function in the `edx` register, as before, but this time I incremented it by 13 bytes before calling the function.

The output of this program is therefore:

```
C:\Temp>dblentry
Hello!
World!
World!

C:\Temp>
```

The first output of "`Hello!\nWorld!`" is from the call to the very beginning of the function, whereas the second output is from the call starting at the "`push offset WLD`" instruction.

I'm wondering if this kind of thing exists in languages that are meant to be a step up from assembler like C, Pascal or FORTRAN.  I know C doesn't let you increment function pointers but is there some other way to achieve this kind of thing?

Comment: It generally doesn't work since skipping function prologue will lead to all kinds of problems. In a higher level language (and even in asm for that matter) you should split it into two separate functions, with one calling the other and let the compiler pick the best implementation.

Comment: I believe older FORTRAN supported multiple entry points for a function, and a quick google search yields https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/g77/Alternate-Entry-Points.html and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn99/index.html

Comment: The actual question is **why** would you want to do this? This is a maintenance nightmare. If up to optimisation: >99% of the programs don't need this. The rest often can be optimised by the compiler and a good structure much better than such 70/80ies BASIC hacks.

Comment: You can use switch() statements without breaks added to create a fall-thru table that emulates this within a function.  Google "Duff's Device" for why someone might want to do something silly like this :)

Comment: This smells a bit like COBOL's `PERFORM ... THRU ...`. There's a good reason why people hate COBOL; when you offer it, people use it, and it's this kind of constructs that make code unmanageable.

Comment: I've just come across some discussion of "single entry, single exit" on FORTRAN: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/118793/3601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can only write functions with multiple entry-points in asm.

You can put labels on all the entry points, so you can use normal direct calls instead of hard-coding the offsets from the first function-name.

This makes it easy to call them normally from C or any other language.

The earlier entry points work like functions that fall-through into the body of another function, if you're worried about confusing tools (or humans) that don't allow function bodies to overlap.

---

You might do this if the early entry-points do a tiny bit of extra stuff, and then fall through into the main function.  It's mainly going to be a code-size saving technique (which might improve I-cache / uop-cache hit rate).

---

Compilers tend to duplicate code between functions instead of sharing large chunks of common implementation between slightly different functions.

However, you can probably accomplish it with only one extra `jmp` with something like:

```
int foo(int a) { return bigfunc(a + 1); }
int bar(int a) { return bigfunc(a + 2); }

int bigfunc(int x) { /* a lot of code */ }
```

See a real example on the [Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-fno-verbose-asm+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell',source:'%0A__attribute__((noinline))+//+noinline+instead+of+making+a+big+function+that+gcc+won!'t+inline%0Aint+bigfunc(int+x)+%7B+return+x+/+1234%3B+%7D%0A%0Aint+foo(int+a)+%7B+return+bigfunc(a+%2B+1)%3B+%7D%0Aint+bar(int+a)+%7B+return+bigfunc(a+%2B+2)%3B+%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

`foo` and `bar` tailcall `bigfunc`, which is slightly worse than having `bar` fall-through into `bigfunc`.  (Having `foo` jump over `bar` into `bigfunc` is still good, esp. if `bar` isn't that trivial.)

---

Jumping into the middle of a function isn't in general safe, because non-trivial functions usually need to save/restore some regs.  So the prologue pushes them, and the epilogue pops them.  If you jump into the middle, then the `pop`s in the prologue will unbalance the stack.  (i.e. pop off the return address into a register, and return to a garbage address).

See also [Does a function with instructions before the entry-point label cause problems for anything (linking)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468465/does-a-function-with-instructions-before-the-entry-point-label-cause-problems-fo)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the longjmp function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/longjmp/

It's a fairly horrible function, but it'll do what you seek.

Comment: longjmp only allows you to return to a point in a parent function.  i.e. back up the call tree, not into an arbitrary function that isn't a parent of the currently running function.  It's another way to make cross-function jumps, but it's not really anything like what the OP was asking for because the requirements for use are so different.

Comment: Yes, longjmp requires pre-execution of the jump entry. But so does the OP sample code.

Comment: No it doesn't!  The OP's `main()` makes a `call` to `(dentry+13)()`.  This would happen the same way regardless of the initial `call` to `dentry()` (which has returned anyway before the second `call`).  It's not even close to similar.