# Aligning a given instruction, but putting the alignment padding somewhere other than immediately before the instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, alignment, nasm, micro-optimization

Is it possible, in nasm (and by extension, yasm) to write a macro or otherwise use pre-processor features to align some particular instruction to a given power of two (or possible a given power of two plus some offset), but inserting the alignment padding not immediately *before* the instruction, but at some arbitrary earlier place?

For example, imagine you had a function where you wanted to align the top of a loop inside the function by 32, you could do it like this:

```
function:
  xor eax, eax
  mov ecx, 1
ALIGN 32
.top:
  add eax, ecx
  inc ecx
  cmp ecx, rdi
  jne .top
```

This will a bunch of `nop` instructions at the point of the `ALIGN 32` directive, which will be executed before entry to the loop (or you could jump over them, but this still executes something in order to jump over the padding.

What you didn't want to add padding inside the function itself, but rather before the function where it will never be executed. For example, if there are 10 bytes before the loop entry, aligning the top of the function to `32N - 10` would do it. Like so:

```
padding_magic .top 32
function:
  xor eax, eax
  mov ecx, 1
ALIGN 32
.top:
  add eax, ecx
  inc ecx
  cmp ecx, rdi
  jne .top
```

Is there some way to accomplish it in nasm, i.e., implement `padding_magic`?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [Does a function with instructions before the entry-point label cause problems for anything (linking)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35468465) if you want to put NOPs (or a short out-of-line block of the function) before the function entry point.  I don't know a clean way to get NASM to figure out how much padding to put, though, to align some *other* location.  (short/long branch displacement optimization makes this non-trivial in the general case: more padding might change the length of other instructions)

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't see it as an almost duplicate. I'm taking it as a given that you can put instructions or other padding wherever you want, `nasm` doesn't care about that (and doesn't need your code to be structured into "functions" as a higher level compiler would). This is all about a macro to emit the right number of bytes.

Comment: Oh.  I thought the "accomplish that" was asking about how to (safely) put NOPs before the label, not about how to get NASM to calculate how many bytes of padding are needed (which I don't think is possible).  You can always accomplish it by padding manually, so maybe make it more explicit that the point of the question is to get NASM to actually do the calculation and padding insertion for you.

Comment: I think the answer is no because the TIMES pseudo-op requires the repetition count to be a critical expression and a critical expression can't refer to a label defined after it. I think the best you can do is insert a fixed amount of padding before the function and then verify that this properly aligns the label.

Comment: @RossRidge - right. I mean it could be possible that some _other_ directive besides `times` could be useful to implement the padding, e.g., `%rep`, but I suspect not, because these things all contribute to the size of the code which needs to be solved in the first pass, and thus probably have the "critical expression" restriction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I managed to figure out a not too hacky way of doing this.  The trick is to assemble the alignment padding after the function and rely segment ordering to put everything in the correct order.

```
%macro BEGIN_PADDED_FUNC 0-1 16
%define _func_name %00
%define _align %1
%define _section_base .text.%[_func_name].

        [SECTION %[_section_base]1 progbits alloc exec nowrite align=_align]
        [SECTION %[_section_base]2 progbits alloc exec nowrite align=1]

_func_name:
%endmacro

%macro ALIGN_PADDED_FUNC 0
%[_func_name].align_point:
%endmacro

%macro END_PADDED_FUNC 0
        [SECTION %[_section_base]1]
        TIMES ((_align - (%[_func_name].align_point - _func_name) % _align) \
               % _align) nop
        __SECT__
%endmacro
```

The above macros would be used like this:

```
function BEGIN_PADDED_FUNC 32
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     ecx, 1

        ALIGN_PADDED_FUNC
.top:
        add     eax, ecx
        inc     ecx
        cmp     ecx, edi
        jne     .top

        END_PADDED_FUNC
```

This code assumes ELF and a reasonable linker and/or linker script that will put a section named `.text.function.1` before `.text.function.2` if that's the order they first appear in the object file. It can probably be modified to work with PECOFF, but I haven't tried this. I've only tested this with NASM, I have no clue whether this would work in YASM.

Comment: That is ... incredibly clever!